# Can browser Windows logon prompt warn to change password first time

Tags: windows, active-directory, authentication

When a user tries to connect via remote desktop, there's a clear error message telling them they first need to change their password before first logon.

When they try to run an application, there's also a warning:

[image]

I would like to know if it's possible to have this warning show up when authenticating through a browser, which currently only shows the following:

[image]